# Divisibility with GCD

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Suppose $F$ is a field, let $f(x), g(x), h(x) \in F[x]$ and $d(x)=\gcd(f(x),g(x))$. If $f(x) \mid h(x)$ and $g(x) \mid h(x)$, prove that $f(x)g(x) \mid d(x)h(x)$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: $f,g\mid h\iff {\rm lcm}(f,g)\mid h,\,$ and $\,{\rm lcm}(f,g) = fg/\gcd(f,g).\,$  Most of the proofs for integers in the linked dupes also work here since $F[x]$ is a PID so enjoys GCDs, unique factorization, Bezout identity etc.

Answer (score 0):

$F[X]$ is a principal domain, so  $d(x)=a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)$

Write $h(x)=u(x)f(x)=v(x)g(x)$.

$d(x)h(x)=$

$(a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x))h(x)=$

$a(x)v(x)f(x)g(x)+b(x)u(x)f(x)g(x)$